# Getting Values From Chunked Array

Tags: php, arrays

I created an array that has values that are in groups of five, but I can't seem to figure out how to fetch them individually as I must in order to use them in calling another function.

Sample array contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Your Full Name
            [1] => Name
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 
            [4] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Your Email
            [1] => EMail
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 
            [4] => 50
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Message
            [1] => Message
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 50
        )
)
```

The PHP snippet for using it:

```php
$Values = array_chunk($Values, 5);
foreach ($Values as $row) :
    foreach ($row as $key) :
        valueTypes($key[0], $key[1], $key[2], $key[3], $key[4], "db_name");   
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. You need only one foreach.

Snippet

```
    $Values = array_chunk($Values, 5);
    foreach ($Values as $key) :
       valueTypes($key[0], $key[1], $key[2], $key[3], $key[4], "db_name");
    endforeach;
```

**Explanation:**

Your array is multidimensional array, if you use two nested `foreach` , `$key` becomes string, and `$key[0]`(Key Index) have no data.

Comment: Thank you and that makes perfect sense! I could have sworn I had tried that and got an error but it does work as you described. I think I got myself confused because I originally had nested arrays so my old brain got stuck on needing a multidimensional array.